# Keep track changes in c++ class

Tags: c++

Will explain this with a simple example.

```
class Vector
{
    float X;
    float Y;
    float _length;
    float Length();
}
```

I only what to calculate Length and assign it to _length if X or Y changed. If none of them changed I just simply return _length.

Comment: it would probably be better to just use the `Length()` function and have it compute the value on the fly.

Comment: This example is really simple but for complex and time consuming calculations this is not an option.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What you need is more akin to lazy evaluation:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation

In more complex classes, keep flags for when things change and only recompute if the flags are set.

Comment: Please select best answer, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to include a guard flag (or "invalid" value) that you flag with `X`/`Y` modifications through:

```
class Vector {
 public:
  Vector(float x = 0.0, float y = 0.0)
  : X{x}, Y{y}, Length{-1.0f}
  { }

  float x() const { return X; }
  float y() const { return Y; }

  float length() const {
    if (Length < 0.0f) {
      Length = sqrt(X*X + Y*Y);
    }
    return Length;
  }

  void setX(float x) { if (X != x) { Length = -1.0f; } X = x; }
  void setY(float y) { if (Y != y) { Length = -1.0f; } Y = y; }

 private:
  float X;
  float Y;
  mutable float Length;
};
```

The `mutable` qualifier means those values are not part of the "logical" state of an object and can be modified even on a `const` instance of `Vector` (via `const` member functions, naturally).

Comment: should it not be possible for `const`functions to change values?

Comment: @Zaiborg this is like the *only* use of `mutable`, and this sort of memoization problem is one of the very few use cases.

Comment: @Zaiborg glad I could help. You also encouraged me to at least clean up/finish the interface, so it's at least properly const-consistent or whatever now.

Comment: @Jeff the last thing to do for performance(?) could be to check if the new `x` and `y` value in `set_()` are different to the current

Comment: @Jeff, you might as well put the `X = x;` into the `if (X != x) { }`.

Comment: @Jeff Also, I'm not convinced by the default parameters to the constructor. For example, what does `Vector v(3.0f);` mean? If you want a default constructor to create a "zero" vector then create one.

Answer (score 1):

Make `x` and `y` private and add two functions like

```
void setX(float x) {
    this -> x = x;
    handleLengthChange();
}
```

and

```
void setY(float y) {
     this -> y = y;
     handleLengthChange();
}
```

The function `handleLengthChange` calculates the new length.
Every class that uses `Vector` will now use the methods above to change x or y.
Since x and y are private, just add two functions to get the values of x and y.

Comment: i like your answer but not the duplicate ;)

Answer (score 0):

make your `float X, Y;` private and add a `bool changed;` to your class as well.
changing X, Y will be done through setters functions that will also set the `bool changed` to false.

whenever you call the function `Length();` it checks for the `bool changed` variable, if false then recalculate.

```
class Vector
    {
        float X;
        float Y;
        bool changed;
        float _length;

        void setX (float val) { // the same for Y
        X = val;
        changed = true;
        }
        float Length(){
           if (changed)
          //compute Length 
            changed = false;
            return ComputedValue;

       } 

}
```

Comment: wouldn't `length()` need to reset `changed` to `false` as well?

Comment: @user3477950: of course, that is the whole idea.
I added it to the code, thanks for pointing that out to me

Answer (score 0):

make `X` and `Y` accessible **only** through setters and getters. Have a boolean value that tells you if `_length` is up to date. On `X` and `Y` setters invalidate `_length` (via that boolean variable). When getting the length check if `_length` if valid. If yes just return it. If not compute it, make it valid and return it.

Answer (score 0):

first thing that came to mind:

```
class Vector
{
public:
    void setX(float x)   {changed = true; X = x;}
    void setY(float y)   {changed = true; Y = y;}

    float length()
    {
        if (changed)
            // calculate

        changed = false;
        return _Length;
    }
private:
    floate X, Y, _Length;
    bool changed;
};
```

edit: i hope now the formating works ...

Comment: make `changed` false after computing it

Comment: wouldn't `length()` need to reset `changed` to `false`?

Comment: racing to have the first answer. Patch it later. :)

Comment: @bolov yeah something like 'oh, i can answer that ... ataaaaack'

Answer (score 0):

Easy, calculate length on the fly from variables `X` and `Y`. This way you'll get always the right length, no matter if `X` or `Y` has changed or not.

```
float Vector::Length()const
{
  return sqrt(X * X + Y * Y);
}
```

Comment: that’s not what he wants. He wants to cache the result of the computation.

Comment: @bolov make things simple not more compicated... Beaty lies in simplicity.

Comment: I don't believe that `sqrt(X * X + Y * Y)` creates a computation bottleneck :).

Comment: not. But that was just a simple example. He need to know how to handle this is a general way to apply it to complex and time-consuming computations.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to maintaining guard flags or "invalid" values [as suggested by Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23767951/3422652) would be to use nullable objects such as pointers, preferably smart pointers. This may be more appropriate when the cache is an object larger than a `float`.

```
class Vector {
  float X;
  float Y;
  mutable std::unique_ptr<float> length_;

 public:
  Vector() : X(0.0f), Y(0.0f) { }
  Vector(float x, float y) : X(x), Y(y) { }

  float x() const { return X; }
  float y() const { return Y; }

  float length() const {
    if (!length_)
      length_ = std::unique_ptr<float>(new float(sqrt(X*X + Y*Y)));
    return *length_;
  }

  void setX(float x) { if (X != x) { length_.reset(); X = x; } }
  void setY(float y) { if (Y != y) { length_.reset(); Y = y; } }
};
```